# Compiler thinks my construction of MatrixXd is a function and not a member

Tags: c++, eigen

I am creating a class that should have a matrix as a protected member declared in the header class of type `MatrixXd` from the Eigen library. The problem is that if I declare it as `MatrixXd name(5, 5);`, where the dimensions of the matrix are between brackets, the compiler sees it as a method of my class, instead of a member.

Can you help me?

Comment: Thanks pingul, I am using `c++11` and your suggestion solved my problem.

Comment: Did you try "using namespace Eigen;" or using "Eigen::MatrixXd;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is called [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), and means that everything that can be parsed as a function, should be. We can solve this by changing the syntax.

In C++11 we can use the initializer list syntax:

```
MatrixXd name{5, 5};
```

Otherwise, casting one of the arguments might work as well:

```
MatrixXd name(int(5), 5);
```